# Navigating an unordered list by keyboard - JQuery

Tags: jquery, keyboard, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an unordered list which is re-orderable using the sortable plugin.

As it doesn't provide keyboard support, I've started to add a custom function for this, starting with being able to navigate through the list by up/down arrowkeys.

Tabbing through the items works fine with tabindex added, however using the up/down arrows results in jumping across multiple list items.

I've setup some test border colours & can see that prev & next items are not being selected correctly.

You can tab into the list on the following page & try to use the arrow keys...

http://jsfiddle.net/qYvNq/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("ul#sortable").sortable();

    $("ul#sortable li").focus(function() {

        $(this).css("border-color","red");

        $previtem = $(this).prev('li');
        $previtem.css("border-color","aqua");

        $nextitem = $(this).next('li');
        $nextitem.css("border-color","lime");

        $(this).keydown(function(e){
            if (e.keyCode == 40) { /* Focus Down */
                $nextitem.focus();
                return false;
            } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { /* Focus Up */
                $previtem.focus();
                return false;
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: You mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/qYvNq/2/ ? Should give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to move the keydown block out of the focus block like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $previtem,
        $nextitem;

    $("ul#sortable").sortable();

    $("ul#sortable li").focus(function() {

        $(this).css("border-color","red");  

        $previtem = $(this).prev('li');
        $previtem.css("border-color","aqua");

        $nextitem = $(this).next('li');
        $nextitem.css("border-color","lime");
    });

    $("ul#sortable").keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 40) { /* Focus Down */
            $nextitem.focus();
            return false;
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { /* Focus Up */
            $previtem.focus();
            return false;
        }
    });     
});
```

Of course, after dragging list items around you will have to make sure to reset the previous and next item as the order then will be a different one.

Comment: Many thanks - separating the focus & keydown solved the issue. I implemented your change & added functionality to reorder with the keyboard. All working nicely.

Answer (score 1):

This clean Working code for keyboard navigation : As follows

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.suggest_div').hide();
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
         if (e.keyCode == 38) { // up
            var selected = $(".selected");
            $(".suggest_container li").removeClass("selected");
            if (selected.prev().length == 0) {
                $(".suggest_container li").siblings().last().addClass("selected").children('a').focus();
            } else {
                selected.prev().addClass("selected").children('a').focus();
            }
        }

        if (e.keyCode == 40) { // down
            var selected = $(".selected");
            $(".suggest_container li").removeClass("selected");
            if (selected.next().length == 0) {
                $(".suggest_container li").siblings().first().addClass("selected").children('a').focus();
            } else {
                selected.next().addClass("selected").children('a').focus();
            }
        }

        if(e.keyCode == 13){ //Enter
            $("#suggest_input").val($('.selected a').attr('username'));
            $(".suggest_div").hide();
        }
    }); 
});
```

The following suggest container is done in ajax ...
Code Follows:

```
function auto_suggest_trigger(){
    var suggest_input = $('#suggest_input').val();

    if(suggest_input != ""){
        $.ajax({ 
            url:'autosuggest_parser.php?query='+suggest_input,
            cache:false,
            success: function(result){
                $('.suggest_div').show();
                $('.suggest_div').html(result);
            }
        });
    }else{
        $('.suggest_div').hide();
    }
}
```

This is form method..

```
<form method="post" name="autosuggest">
<label>Type Here :</label>  <input type="text" name="suggest_input" class="text_input" id="suggest_input"  onkeyup="auto_suggest_trigger()" onkeypress="auto_suggest_trigger()"placeholder="Type in here..."/>
</form>
```

Now You can write php or any other code in post the file in ajax..were i have return in php.

Coded By Shaikh Arbaaz.